# iOs like NSScroller

Tags: cocoa, ios, scrollbar

I am looking an iOS like NSScroller
- the track only appear when scrolling
- inertia support
- same look and feel.

Do you know if something like this already exists?

Thanks and regards,

Answer (score 0):

Not that I'm aware of.  You would likely have to subclass NSScrollView in addition to NSScroller.  Subclassing NSScroller would allow you to produce the look and feel of the scrollbar that is only visible during scrolling.

The inertial scrolling would have to be built into the NSScrollView itself, although I know that Mac's using a trackpad and have the option to turn on inertial scrolling in System Preferences.

Comment: Yes, using a trackpad already has inertial scrolling. I would advise against using inertial scrolling outside of trackpad use as it would confuse the user when they let go and it keeps scrolling.